# PostgreSQL: trigger function to grant privileges in a loop

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table users:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial primary key,
    name text,
    status text,
    tier text,
    project text[]);
```

Column project is an array of schema names. I'd like to create a trigger function that grants a set of privileges to a user when a user is added to the table. A single user can have access to multiple schemas, so my idea is to loop through an array of schema names.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION common.add_user()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    u_name text = NEW.name;
    m text;
    project text[] = NEW.project;
begin 
    FOREACH m IN ARRAY project LOOP
        EXECUTE 'GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ' || m || ' TO ' || u_name;
    END LOOP;
RETURN NEW;
end;
$BODY$;
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_user
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON common.users
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE common.add_user();
```

When I add an entry to common.users table:

```
INSERT INTO common.users (name, project) VALUES ('user01', '{"schema01", "schema02"}');
```

It executes without errors, an entry is added to the table but no privileges are granted. Of course I made sure that the insert query is executed by a user that can actually grant those privileges.

Comment: You don't really need a trigger. `alter default privileges` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: "*no privileges are granted*" - how do you know?

Comment: Privileges are granted to defined users in the database cluster. Adding a row to a `users` table does not create a user at the level of the database cluster. Does every row in the table have a corresponding user in the cluster?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name AFAIK there's no way to grant default privileges for schema. I am using RLS on tables so I'm okay with being a bit loose with grants as long as my RLS policies are restrictive enough, but some work has to be done in a trigger function anyway.
Bergi I'm on a test environment so I can test it with a user that I am trying to assign privileges to. Also there's no entry in postgres log apart from INSERT in common.users.
Patrick Yes, of course user is defined beforehand. I'm trying to automate the rest of privileges so that all I have to do via terminal is to create user.

Comment: @Dreamscape No I mean what did you test that did fail after the privilege was (not) granted?

Comment: @Bergi I tested if user01 can list tables in schema01 and schema02. It cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was pretty close, maybe an issue with execute syntax inside loop? Anyway, this does exactly what I want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION common.add_user()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    u_name text = NEW.name;
    m text;
    project text[] = NEW.project;
begin 
    EXECUTE 'GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE x TO ' ||u_name;
    EXECUTE 'GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO ' ||u_name;
    EXECUTE 'GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA common TO ' ||u_name;
    EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA common TO ' ||u_name;
    FOREACH m IN ARRAY project LOOP
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA %1$s to %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA %1$s to %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA %1$s to %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA %1$s to %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLES to %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS to %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCES to %2$s', m, u_name);
    END LOOP;
RETURN NEW;
end;
$BODY$;
```

I also wanted to be able to easily manage access to projects (schemas) by modifying value in column project. Together with RLS on tables managing privileges is now pretty simple.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION common.update_user()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    u_name text = OLD.name;
    m text;
    n text;
    deleted text[];
    added text[];
begin 
    deleted := ARRAY(select * from unnest(OLD.project) except select * from unnest(NEW.project));
    added := ARRAY(select * from unnest(NEW.project) except select * from unnest(OLD.project));
    FOREACH m IN ARRAY deleted LOOP
        Raise warning 'REVOKED ACCESS ON PROJECT % FROM %', m, u_name;
        EXECUTE format('REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA %1$s FROM %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA %1$s FROM %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('REVOKE USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA %1$s FROM %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('REVOKE EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA %1$s FROM %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS FROM %2$s', m, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s REVOKE USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCES FROM %2$s', m, u_name);
    END LOOP;
    FOREACH n IN ARRAY added LOOP
        Raise warning 'GRANTED ACCESS ON PROJECT % TO %', n, u_name;
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA %1$s to %2$s', n, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA %1$s to %2$s', n, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA %1$s to %2$s', n, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA %1$s to %2$s', n, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLES to %2$s', n, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS to %2$s', n, u_name);
        EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %1$s GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCES to %2$s', n, u_name);
    END LOOP;
RETURN NEW;
end;
$BODY$;
```